# How can I present a boolean as "yes" or "no"?

Tags: jsp, boolean, jstl

How can I replace true and false with yes or no using JSP and JSTL?

I have values TRUE and FALSE in my table.

I want when I retrieve these values using jstl on my jsp pages the true false will replace with YES AND NO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest using a tagfile.

Create the tagfile, (say, `/WEB-INF/tags/yesno.tag`) with something like this:

```
<%@ attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:choose><c:when test="${value}">yes</c:when><c:otherwise>no</c:otherwise></c:choose>
```

Then in your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<tags:yesno value="${MyBoolean}"/>
```

The tagfile is a bit cumbersome, but it's well encapsulated and reusable.

Comment: You should then vote and accept this answer (and review [your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/346077/mansoor) as well). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/faq to learn how to use stackoverflow properly :)

Comment: For others, note the missing quote `<tags:yesno value=${MyBoolean}"/>` should be `<tags:yesno value="${MyBoolean}"/>`

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to take advantage of JSP Expression Language and use the following in your JSPs:

```
${myBoolean ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
```

Comment: I like this way more, it requires no tag-programming. A little off-topic, in JSF (yes, I know that it is not wanted) you can do the same with some EL code: `<h:outputText value="#{product.productAvailability ? msg.CHOICE_YES : msg.CHOICE_NO}" />`, by `product` is the underlaying entity (data model), `productAvailability` the `java.lang.Boolean` flag and `msg` is the message bundle.

Comment: Your way btw. is not internationalizable as it is English language only but still I up-voted it as it is small and simple (`KISS`).

Answer (score 0):

```
${(countryList.legal eq 'Y')?'Yes':'No'}
```

or

```
${(countryList.status eq 1)?'Active':'Inactive'}
```

Comment: Not booleans and boils down to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32779992/880619